# How to add a Facebook like button to email

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-like

How do I add a *Like* button is on the actual email that I send, and clicking it leads to a landing page on my website?

That means I want to add a *Like* button with HTML email newsletter that I send. And if anyone *like* it after that, I want to redirect them to my site.

Comment: To indicate what? That they like the email? What would that do exactly?

Comment: no, like to my fan page. and after that I want to redirect them into my landing page. is it possible..?

Comment: Just link them to your fan page. How can they know whether they like the page or not if they can't see it?

Comment: no, First i want to add like button of fan page to the email news letter.when they click it  they want to show its publish in there time line and show other  friend like it as normal like. so how can I do that..?

Comment: You can't like something you haven't seen. That's just not possible. Link to your fan page and put the like button on the fan page.

Comment: ok, thanks. thats the thing I ask. Is it work as normal like button that we embedded in the web page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this - "like" buttons can only be attached to URL's.  If you have a URL that somehow represents that specific email message then you might be able to get away with that.
Another thing to note is that not all email clients allow (by default) HTML content in the body of the email message - especially not iFrames...
What you might want to do is simply place a link to your website inside the email message and once the user lands on your website he/she can decide whether or not they want to "like" your URL.

Comment: anyway can i add only like button with email news letter ?

Comment: The only possible way I could imagine doing this is by placing an iFrame version of the like button in the email.  However (at least through gmail), the iFrame is not displayed.  For other methods you'll need to implement the JavaScript SDK and you simply can not do that inside an email - it just doesn't work this way.

Comment: @miuranga, may I ask why you decided to reverse the "accept"?

Comment: hehe - no worries - I thought maybe you disagreed with my answer =]

Answer (score 5):

You can create an html version of your email (if you have a website), and instead of the person seeing the content within the email, they are now on an html version of that site on your website. In your email it would be an image or similar that says [VIEW EMAIL] or something like that. That will link to the HTML version mentioned above.  You can create the LIKE button on that page which can then post on their timeline. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Add `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.YOURWEBSITEADDRESS.com%2F` to your `href`. It will open a Facebook like/share page.

Comment: But "sharing" your website URL is not the same functionality as liking a facebook page, which is what the question seems to ask. Just worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it using [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail). It will show you full codes and your *like* button URL will be a [clickable link](http://www.onlineearningjobs.com/). So, it's just not possible to add a Facebook button. I tried both iframe and JavaScript versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following link: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/yourpagename

This will open a new tab with a like button and a list of the users friends who already like the page...